# Javascript switch always default

Tags: javascript, loops, switch-statement, default

I am working on a switch that sets 2 variables based on the value like so:

```
switch(_drukte) {
    case "normaal": 
        _gradients.push("green");
        _widths.push("20%");
    break;
    case "drukker": 
        _gradients.push("yellow");
        _widths.push("40%");
    break;
    case "gezellig druk": 
        _gradients.push("orange");
        _widths.push("60%");
    break;
    case "druk": 
        _gradients.push("red");
        _widths.push("80%");
    break;
    case "vol": 
        _gradients.push("full");
        _widths.push("100%");
    break;
    default:
        _gradients.push("green");
        _widths.push("20%");
    break;
}
```

For some reason this ALWAYS calls the default.
_drukte is from an AJAX get on a JSON file and the value changes with a loop.
I've alerted the value of _drukte and it is as expected (currently it's "normaal", "drukker", "gezellig druk", "druk" and "vol").
I tried messing up the other cases (even making it invalid javascript) and it just calls the default.

Anybody know why?

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Show as an example with an actual value for `_drukte`. And do a `console.log(_drukte)` before your switch statement, likely there's some problem with your ajax.

Comment: First define __gradients as a hash table then try to run the code..

Comment: FWIW? @AdrianoVaroliPiazza, _gradients is set higher up in the code with `var _gradients = [];`. I wouldn't try to populate a non-existing array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to lean too far out of the window, but I would almost guarantee you that the return value from your *ajax request* does not fit 100% your `case`'es.

If I were you, I'd directly `console.log( _drukte );` before that `switch` statement.

Maybe white-spaces ? Capital letters ?

Thats the best answer I can provide without seeing your actual code, so try to figure out which exact value is contained by `_drukte` when the `switch statement` gets encountered.

Comment: Perhaps even a scope issue with the loop the OP talked about, or it could be that the `switch` isn't part of the readystatechange/success callback

Comment: console.log does not seem to be doing anything.

Comment: @jAndy Nevermind it not working, Fetch was acting up. When I console.log _drukte it shows me 5 values: ["normaal"]["drukker"]["gezellig druk"]["druk"]["vol"] (as shown in the console).

Comment: So the problem is that you get an array and you think you have a string, that would be why it's always defaulting.

Comment: But It's not an array because it runs over console.log 5 times and assigns a different value every time.

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza I've found the issue. Turns out _drukte actually IS an array. I can call _drukte and _drukte[0] and they both give me the same values, but only _drukte[0] actually works with the switch.